# Is there a naming convention for open chords?

Tags: chords, notation

I am studying a guitar piece where an F# minor chord is spelled as `F# / C# / A` (R / P5 / m3) over strings 5, 3 and 2.

I found out that chords spanning over more than a octave are called *open chords* (not in the guitar open string sense of course).

For triads, this is the only possible open position of course, but with sevenths for instance there are more permutations possible, respectively 3 and 5 on top.

Is there a way to notate that like for close chords inversions (e.g. 6/3, 6/4)?

Comment: the question may be a duplicate of https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/84162

Comment: Related, but that covers the general case too, asking for other ways to name them. I did like your "skip" system as an alternative!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would notate the exact voicing of a chord (open or close) by writing it out note by note.

Chord symbols were not designed to show the exact voicings only give a general sense of what the harmony is. The bass note is the only exact voicing that is notate and this is because the bass note greatly defines the overall harmony. Think of it as short hand harmony as it's meant to give an idea rather than an exact set in stone voicing.